# Decimal tab in rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf, richtext

I have some content that will be displayed in a C# rich text box.  I would like to have one of the columns displayed with the decimal points aligned:

```
//  Title                      Price
//  Item1                     1234.56
//  Item2                       78.90
//  Item3                        1.2
```

Below is code that was used in a (failed) attempt to build a string in memory before passing it to the RichTextBox control.

```
message = "";
message += @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033" +
           @"{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2509;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 TEST RICH TEXT BOX \par";
message += @"\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\tx4000\ul\b Title\ulnone\b0\tab\ul\b Price\ulnone\b0\line\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\tx5000\tqdec\par ";
message += String.Format(@"{0}\tab {1} \line ", "Item1", 1234.56);
message += String.Format(@"{0}\tab {1} \line ", "Item2", 78.90);
message += String.Format(@"{0}\tab {1} \line ", "Item3", 1.2);
message += @"\par}";
```

using this the result looks like:

```
//  Title                      Price
//  Item1                     1234.56
//  Item2                     78.90
//  Item3                     1.2
```

I moved the \tqdec (decimal tab) command before the \tx5000 (tab 5000 twips from left edge) without success.  Also attempted using the \tqr (tab align right) command without success.

Suggestions are appreciated

Comment: my suggestion is anyway to use a font like Courier New which is constant spacing. Won't solve everything but "minimizes" the noise while testing.

Comment: The RTF is wrong.  Word can generate RTF that aligns properly in Wordpad when I try it, reverse-engineering the rtf is a pita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I'm not sure if your real intent is to modify RTF source text or if you are doing it only for the purpose of aligning your text.  In the following, I am assuming that you are working with a normal string where tabs are escaped as \t and new lines as \r\n.  (You should not need to edit the source RTF property to enter text under normal circumstances...  I assume you have a good reason for doing so...)

Does this code work?  Do you mind the trailing 0's?  By the way, tabs won't help you align text.  You must use the string format options to insert spaces where you need them.

```
        message += String.Format("{0}\t {1,10:#####0.00} \r\n", "Item1", 1234.56);
        message += String.Format("{0}\t {1,10:#####0.00} \r\n", "Item2", 78.90);
        message += String.Format("{0}\t {1,10:#####0.00} \r\n", "Item3", 1.2);
```

Output:

```
Item1     1234.56 
Item2       78.90 
Item3        1.20
```

Another approach is to insert a table (I believe that RTF supports tables, right?), then pad your numbers with 0's at the right and finally right-align the column as Excel would do.

Comment: As you guessed, the code in my application is significantly more complex than the simplified example I posted.  I use RTF so that some programatically defined phrases can be output in bold or underlined. The reason for attempting to use tabs to align columns is due to the use of proportional fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms, the RichTextBox does not support aligned tabs.  You can open up WordPad and see that it doesn't have those options either.

One trick you might want to try is to use tables with cell alignments.  Unfortunately, the RichTextBox control doesn't support tables either (at least in .net 3.5, I don't know about .net 4), but you can force it with something like this:

```
public class rtbEx : RichTextBox
{
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      var prams = base.CreateParams;
      if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
        prams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";

      return prams;
    }
  }
}
```

After that, I usually use Microsoft Word to make my tables and copy/paste that into my richtextbox, then tweak the rtf code accordingly.

Kind of a long way to try to go to do something like this, but it *might* help you.

Comment: Your assumption on WinForms is correct.  Thank you for the work around and the fact that RichText does not support aligned tabs(+1).  However the users for my current app would not appreciate aligned decimal places enough to implement this solution in this app.  Fortunately, the answer will be in StackOverflow for an application that does require it.